# How to set value of mysql MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations

Tags: mysql, storage

I am getting following error:

> Got temporary error 233 'Out of operation records in transaction coordinator (increase MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations)' from NDBCLUSTER

While inserting data into ndb table.

Can anyone explain more about this error. Also in my config.ini I dont have this parameter set. Is there any way I can see the default value of this variable. as I canot see this variable when I am using commmand SHOW VARIABLES.

To set this variable do I also need to change the `MaxMaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions` and `MaxNoOfLocalOperations`.

Answer (score 5):

The default value for MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations is 32768 but you can increase this value by editing your ndb_mgm config i.e. /etc/mysql/ndb_mgmd.cnf

and adding something like

```
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=100000
```

When updaing the MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations value you should also update MaxNoOfLocalOperations. The rule of thumb is to make MaxNoOfLocalOperations 10% larger than MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations so you would have.

```
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=100000
MaxNoOfLocalOperations=110000
```

Comment: Hi, I searched for this file, but I did not find this file. Is it same as mysql-cluster Config.ini file? as i have just now done setup of mysql-cluster.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. It is the same as where you configure your cluster.